# Connecting To port...Could not open connection to the host, on port 23: Connect failed

Tags: cmd, proxy, telnet

I could not make the telnet port command execute.
I did what was told in this [link](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753164%28v=ws.10%29.aspx).
the snapshots of my cmd are:

[image]

what else shall i do to execute these commands?

[image: 1][image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `telnet` command connects to the host you specify as the first argument on the port you specify as the second argument (or 23, if you only specify a single argument).

When you tried to execute `telnet port`, it tried to connect to the server `port` on port 23. Since there is no server with the address `port` (unless you specified it in your pc's hosts file), `telnet` couldn't connect to it.

I'm guessing the second command failed, because `www.udacity.com` doesn't accept connections on port 8080 (the second argument of the command).

I don't see any instructions in the link you provided.

**EDIT**: If you're trying to connect to localhost, use `telnet localhost` (to connect to port 23) or `telnet localhost <port>` (replace `<port>` with the port you are trying to connect to).

Comment: if you see the first image the port is set to 23

Comment: Are you trying to connect to your own PC?

Comment: yes i am trying to connect to local host

Comment: thankyou on that how to connect to udacity??

Comment: Why do you want to connect to udacity? Unless it's your personal site, it's probably impossible.

Comment: `telnet www.udacity.com 80`  <--- this connects but I'm not sure what you expect from this.

Comment: @WannaBeCoder since you haven't replied for 21 hours, I'm guessing this answer was useful to you. If so, consider marking it as answer.

Comment: ```telnet server port```

Answer (score 1):

I also faced same problem. Solution, after adding feature for telnet server, a new service is added for this but is in by default disabled state. So make sure service is running and in non disable mode.